# Path to .class file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I know eclipse automatically build java files.When compiling we will get Class files normally.When we run java file from eclipse where we can see generated .class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the bin folder of your eclipse project

Answer (score 2):

[image] 1. For this you have to go to Window->Show view->Navigator 
 2. Now there will be a window opened on left side where you can explore all folders including "build" folder.
 3. Here in build folder go to ->classes->This is the place where you can Find all your .class Files

Hope This will answer your Quest .

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your project name in Project Explorer and click Properties from menu
2. Go to Java Build Path from left menu on the popup
3. Click on Source tab on the page
4. See the Default Output Folder option which is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the project build properties > build path option.

- Open build path settings for your project by right clicking
- Go to source option
- There you can see source directories as well as **default output folder**. That is where the class files will be generated.

Either you can set it during project creation like this: here output folder is **ptll**
[image]

Or you can see the default output folder for java in preferences > java

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have both **src** and **target** folders in maven project path once project build is done, Go to Windows -> ShowView -> Navigator -> (Project Path) -> target(folder) -> classes(where you can find all the classes that compiled from the src folder)